# Accessing Nested Collection View JSON data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, xamarin.forms

I have a nested JSON data to be accessed. The data is structured into nested data which i want to have into one.

I modeled the JSON response into c# model classes

```
public class Customer1
{
    public string district { get; set; }
    public string feeder { get; set; }
    public string feeder_code { get; set; }
    public string transformer { get; set; }
    public string dss_code { get; set; }
    public string database_match { get; set; }
    public string accountnumber { get; set; }
    public string meterno { get; set; }
    public TransactionalDetails transactional_details { get; set; }
}

public class Customer2
{
    public string accountNumber { get; set; }
    public string meterNumber { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int billedAmount { get; set; }
    public object billedDate { get; set; }
    public string lastPayDate { get; set; }
    public Lastpayment lastpayment { get; set; }
}

public class Lastpayment
{
    public string transactionRef { get; set; }
    public int units { get; set; }
    public string transactionDate { get; set; }
    public string transactionId { get; set; }
    public int transactionBookId { get; set; }
    public int amountPaid { get; set; }
    public int mscPaid { get; set; }
    public string invoiceNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Queryresult
{
    public string responseMessage { get; set; }
    public Customer1 customer1 { get; set; }
    public int responseCode { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public ObservableCollection<Customer1> Customer1 { get; set; }
    public int row_count { get; set; } 
}

public class Root
{
    public bool error { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionalDetails
{
    public Queryresult queryresult { get; set; }
    public bool status { get; set; }
}
```

I also created the following code to access the data using the root.

```
  var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<root>(readTask);
  ObservableCollection<Customer1> innerData2 = data.result.Customer1;
```

My challenge is that i want to have **Customer1**, **Customer2** and **last payment** data merged into a single collection view.

with what i have done, i can only access customer1 data. how can i access all into a single collection?

Comment: `Customer2` is not referenced anywhere in the data.

Comment: public class Result
    {
    public ObservableCollection<Customer1> Customer1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Customer2> Customer2 { get; set; }
    public int row_count { get; set; } 
}

@Jason so i adjusted and referenced it from the Result model. but then how do i access all into one observable collection?.

Comment: that is `Customer1`, not `Customer2`

Comment: 'var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<root>(readTask);'
  'ObservableCollection<Customer1> innerData2 = data.result.Customer1;'

 'var data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<root>(readTask);'
  'ObservableCollection<Customer2> innerData = data2.result.Customer2;'

Do i have to create an observable collection for each ? how do i merge all please

Comment: I have no idea.  You haven't actually posted your data.  It sounds like you have two completely different data sources you need to somehow merge together.  That really has nothing to do with Xamarin and is just a basic data management problem.